# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when accessing jar that is present in external build path

Tags: java, ssh, build, path

I've added a new jar to my project's external build path in eclipse:

C:\folder\projectFolder\lib\jcabi-ssh-1.5.2.jar

Added import statements:

```
import com.jcabi.ssh.SSH;
import com.jcabi.ssh.Shell;
```

Added commands to test it:

```
Shell shell = new SSH(...);
String stdout = new Shell.Plain(shell).exec("echo 'Hello, world!'");
```

There are no issues showing in the IDE before running the project.

Upon running the project, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
```

After following some other posts, I've seen that:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

returns a list containing:

```
C:\folder\projectFolder\lib\jcabi-ssh-1.5.2.jar
```

What else is missing in this instance? All my other jars in the external build path are working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The jar file jcabi-ssh-1.5.2.jar only contains classes in the package `com.jcabi.ssh`, but that missing class does not belong to that package.

So what's happening is that your code does not explicitly reference the JSchException class, which is why everything's OK in your IDE.  However, when you run the app and some jcabi class says "throw new JSchException" - that's when the JVM starts looking for it.

`JSchException` can be found in a JSch jar.  You can download it from, for example, http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/.

However, beware that that jar file is not the only dependency that the jcabi classes have - you can see the full list of "Compile Dependencies" sections in maven repository sites such as :

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcabi/jcabi-ssh/1.5.2
```

so you will have to download all those as well, and all the Compile Dependencies that all those have, and all the compile dependencies .....

Much easier is to have the system load all the dependencies for you - which is what maven and ivy and others do.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification racaman. Why couldn't they have just self contained it, like other packages?

Comment: https://github.com/hudson/ganymed-ssh-2  is doing the trick!  Google search for ganymed-ssh2.jar though.